# How can I copy a statically named file to another location with increasing numerical suffixes?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I've got three files in a directory that appear via another process:

```
c:\result\results-a.txt
c:\result\results-b.txt
c:\result\results-c.txt
```

Each time they all appear, I'd like to copy them to another directory with an increasing numerical suffix/prefix, once the files are copied they can be deleted.  Every time the batch file starts, it can start with the number 0 (it doesn't have to scan the target directory and continue).

Ex.  The first time the files all appear,  the target directory might look like this:

```
c:\archive\results-a.0000.txt
c:\archive\results-b.0000.txt
c:\archive\results-c.0000.txt
```

The second time they appear, the target directory would then contain:

```
c:\archive\results-a.0000.txt
c:\archive\results-b.0000.txt
c:\archive\results-c.0000.txt
c:\archive\results-a.0001.txt
c:\archive\results-b.0001.txt
c:\archive\results-c.0001.txt
```

And so on.  I'm comfortable piecing this together in a BASH enviroment, but my client requires this be done on a Windows NT (Windows 7, actually) machine.  Could someone get me started?

[Edit - Answer]
Thanks to Joey below, this is what I ended up coding.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=0

:loop
call :test_file %1\results1.txt
call :test_file %1\results2.txt
call :test_file %1\results3.txt

timeout 2 /nobreak >nul
call :movefiles
timeout 2 /nobreak >nul
goto loop

:test_file
timeout 2 /nobreak >nul
if not exist %1 goto :test_file
goto :eof

:lz
set LZ=000%Counter%
set LZ=%LZ:~-4%
goto :eof

:movefiles
for %%f in (C:\test\*.txt) do (
    call :lz
    move "%%f" "c:\tmp\c-!LZ!-%%~nxf"
)
set /a Counter+=1
goto :eof
```

A very nice introduction to batch programming.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a few pieces for this to work.

1. First of all, a counter:

   ```
   set Counter=0
   ```
2. Then a subroutine that pads the value with leading zeroes:

   ```
   :lz
     set LZ=000%Counter%
     set LZ=%LZ:~-4%
   goto :eof
   ```

   The `%LZ:~-4%` is a substring operation that retains the last four characters of the variable value. In this case this is a number, zero-padded to four places.
3. A loop that checks for files in a certain location:

   ```
   :loop
     if exist c:\result\*.txt call :movefiles
     timeout 2 /nobreak >nul
   goto loop
   ```

   Fairly readable, this one, I guess.
4. A subroutine that moves the files away:

   ```
   :movefiles
     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     for %%f in (C:\result\*.txt) do (
       rem Generate the zero-padded number
       call :lz
       move "%%f" "some\target\directory\%%~nf.!LZ!%%~xf"
     )
     endlocal
     rem Increment the counter for next use
     set /a Counter+=1
   goto :eof
   ```

Piecing all that together leaves you with

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=0

:loop
  if exist c:\result\*.txt call :movefiles
  timeout 2 /nobreak >nul
goto loop

:lz
  set LZ=000%Counter%
  set LZ=%LZ:~-4%
goto :eof

:movefiles
  for %%f in (C:\result\*.txt) do (
    call :lz
    move "%%f" "some\target\directory\%%~nf.!LZ!%%~xf"
  )
  set /a Counter+=1
goto :eof
```

It can be adapted to remember its last value. However, this will only work if the batch file resides in a writable location.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=0
call :init

:loop
  if exist c:\result\*.txt call :movefiles
  timeout 2 /nobreak >nul
goto loop

:lz
  set LZ=000%Counter%
  set LZ=%LZ:~-4%
goto :eof

:movefiles
  for %%f in (C:\result\*.txt) do (
    call :lz
    move "%%f" "some\target\directory\%%~nf.!LZ!%%~xf"
  )
  set /a Counter+=1
  >>%~dpnx0 echo set Counter=%Counter%
goto :eof

:init
```

Note that the last line (`:init`) must be terminated with a line break (or better two; I had some issues sometimes with just one in my testing here). This essentially creates a subroutine at the end of the batch file that sets the counter repeatedly until it arrives at its last value.

It isn't exactly fast, though. There will be one `set` call per counter increment at the end, and all those will be run initially.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: @Jamie: I have to admit, this was written directly into the editor here, so it's untested.

Comment: I used the second last code block ... I'll post the code I used in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should get you started. Drop this in a file called `incrementName.bat` and then run it several times in succession.

```
@echo off
goto :start
  --------------------------------------------

  incrementName.bat

  shows how to generate a filename with a monotonically
  increasing numeric portion.

  Run this several times in succession to see it in action.

  Mon, 18 Apr 2011  12:51

  --------------------------------------------

:START
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :GETNEXTFILENAME rammalamma.txt
echo Next: %nextname%

@REM copy self to that new name.
copy %0 %nextname%

GOTO END



--------------------------------------------
:GETNEXTFILENAME
@REM this is a subroutine.
@REM %1 is the basename. This logic assumes a 3-character 
@REM filename extension. 
set fname=%1
set ext=%fname:~-3%
set base=%fname:~0,-4%
set idx=0
:toploop1
  @set NUM=00000!idx!
  set nextname=%base%.!NUM:~-5!.%ext%
  if EXIST !nextname! (
    if !idx! GTR 99999 goto:FAIL
    set /a idx=!idx! + 1
    goto:toploop1
  )
)
:Success
goto:EOF
:Fail - overflow
set nextname=%base%.xxxxx.%ext%
goto:EOF
--------------------------------------------


:END
endlocal
```

Comment: »This logic assumes a 3-character filename extension.« ... because `%~dpn1` and `%~x1` are too cumbersome to use?